Was supposed to be co-signer on auto for daughter but I’m listed the buyer
I agreed to be a co-signer for my daughter. After all the paperwork was completed, which I never signed any of it, I found out I was the buyer and she was not on the loan or title at all.
I live in another state. I never signed any loan agreements or paperwork, only app to be a co-signer.
What can I do?

only app to be a co-signer - that's the paperwork. The "app to be a co-signer" is officially called "a loan application".

You say you "agreed to be a co-signer". Do you mean verbally, or you agreed in writing?

What State is the dealership in?

What country is this in? The tag was added by an editor @mhorsan_psprep but might be based on nothing more than the use of the word 'state'?

I never signed any of it ... I don't understand how you thought you would be a "co-signer", if you never signed anything.

This is common.  Car dealerships lie.  There really isn't such thing as a cosigner in most car transactions, only a co-owner.  Not only are you responsible for the loan, you are exposed to a liability suit if your anyone harms someone or something with this car.  This includes if your daughter loans this vehicle to a friend.
It is almost always best to arrange outside financing prior to going to a dealership.  This is also your remedy.  After a few payments, see if your daughter can obtain financing for the car from her bank or credit union.

I am responsible even though I never signed any paperwork regarding the auto loan

You may have a fraud case, perhaps contact a lawyer.  They probably forged your signature.

You said you signed application to be a co-signer. That might have been enough.

@keshlam can't transfer a car with a lien on it, that's what liens are for.

@littleadv: Point granted. So when daughter pays off the loan it can be hers. ... Until then you have the complication of billing her for the insurance and any excuse tax too...

@keshlam love "excuse tax," as if they just needed one more excuse to tax us a little bit more!

@nuggethead: Of course I meant excise tax, but I like the accident too. As opposed to stupidity tax, which is how I categorize spending that I should have been able to avoid.

There really isn't such thing as a cosigner in most car transactions, only a co-owner this applies to all states or some have it?

@Suncatcher my reference to this is the litany of questions, on this site, that are the shock and horror of people finding out they are in a co-owner situation and not a co-signer.  Given the sheer volume I would say it is all states.

Man, I'm glad I walked into my recent purchase with a loan from my bank. The dealership hated it though.

@ChthonicOne yes they do.  With new cars they frequently make more money in the finance office then they do from the sale.  Again, they lie, tempting you with special rates from the manufacturer and then jam you into a loan that is worse than terms you could have gotten on your own.

I had a similar experience last year (car was paid for in cash, but, I was on the title, not my son).  First, the loan and title are two separate issues.
About the title.  You will have to do a little reading on how car sales work in your State.  In mine (TX), and probably all, there is a sales contract for a car.  Whoever signs the sales contract goes on the title.  The contract may also give details about how titling is going to proceed, but there's going to be State laws governing this process.  So get a copy of the sales contract ASAP an look it over.
In my State, I didn't even have to contact a lawyer, because there is an enforcement agency to report non-compliant car dealerships.  I'm sure your State has one too.  You'll want to look at the State where the dealership resides.  They probably have a portal to submit a complaint online.  It'll be a pretty open-and-shut case if you're not on the sales contract and they put you on the title.
As for the loan, no personal experience here, but again get a copy of the loan docs and report the violation to a State enforcement agency.  I think it's another easy case for them.
My feeling is employees at car dealerships are instructed to do illegal things like this, and they get away with it most of the time because people don't know what to do.  Lawyers are expensive and there isn't a lot of $ damages so that route isn't worth it.  But the State agencies are really good at cracking down and fining dealerships as the case may be.  My case was resolved in a few weeks, and boy did the car dealership change their tune after the State went in there!

I suspect it's much more that after a confused conversation with a young person who is bringing in a pile of money/credit with their parent's signature, and several rounds of telephone between different dealership employees, there are a lot of opportunities for honest mistakes.
